# Two-Way SSL Authentication with Apache 2.2 and OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, openssl

I have a CentOS 6 server running Apache 2.2.15 with OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips.  I am trying to setup two-way SSL authentication for a specific location in my web root. A 3rd party has provided both a public (plain-text) and private (binary) certificate.

I need some guidance on how to include both the public and private certs to get the handshaking working, as I am getting the following error:

> Re-negotiation handshake failed: Not accepted by client!?

Here's what I have in my /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf file pertaining to this section:

```
<Location /api/path/>
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/private/public.cer
SSLVerifyClient require
SSLVerifyDepth 10
SSLOptions +StdEnvVars +ExportCertData +OptRenegotiate
</Location>
```

Admittedly I am not an SSL expert.  I know enough to get certs installed and working.  I have turned logginf to 'debug' level.  I have tried to follow these guides:

http://www.stefanocapitanio.com/configuring-two-way-authentication-ssl-with-apache/

http://www.cafesoft.com/products/cams/ps/docs32/admin/ConfiguringApache2ForSSLTLSMutualAuthentication.html

Thanks in advance!

Full ssl.conf file:

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
Listen 443

SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin

SSLSessionCache         shmcb:/var/cache/mod_ssl/scache(512000)
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

SSLMutex default

SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom  256
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
#SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/random  512
#SSLRandomSeed connect file:/dev/random  512
#SSLRandomSeed connect file:/dev/urandom 512

SSLCryptoDevice builtin
#SSLCryptoDevice ubsec
<VirtualHost *:443>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/staging-site"
ServerName staging.site.com:443
ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
LogLevel debug

SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW

SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/cert.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/private.key
#SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/server-chain.crt
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/rapidssl.crt

#SSLVerifyClient require
#SSLVerifyDepth  10

#   Access Control:
#<Location />
#SSLRequire (    %{SSL_CIPHER} !~ m/^(EXP|NULL)/ \
#            and %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_O} eq "Snake Oil, Ltd." \
#            and %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_OU} in {"Staff", "CA", "Dev"} \
#            and %{TIME_WDAY} >= 1 and %{TIME_WDAY} <= 5 \
#            and %{TIME_HOUR} >= 8 and %{TIME_HOUR} <= 20       ) \
#           or %{REMOTE_ADDR} =~ m/^192\.76\.162\.[0-9]+$/
#</Location>

<Location /path/api/>
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/private/3rdpartyprivate.cer
    SSLVerifyClient require
    SSLVerifyDepth 10
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars +ExportCertData +OptRenegotiate
</Location>

#   SSL Engine Options:
#SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
<Files ~ "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php3?)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Files>
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>

#   SSL Protocol Adjustments:
SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

#   Per-Server Logging:
CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Try removing the SSLOptions directive.

Comment: Have a look at bettercrypto.org and cipherli.st for recommendations on how to securely set up TLS

Comment: @fuero I did try w/ out that option with no success.  Just not sure how to include both the public and private cert? Will take a look at the 2 sites you mentioned.  Thanks,

Comment: Show us your complete SSL config.

Comment: @fuero Do I use the public key for the SSLCACertificateFile value? What do I do w/ the private binary key, if anything? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are not using the correct certificates in the correct place.
You are supposed to use the server certificate issued by a trusted CA in the `SSLCertificateFile` (certificate in PEM format), `SSLCertificateKeyFile` (key in PEM format matching the cert), and `SSLCertificateChainFile` (certificates starting from the host cert's issuer certificate up to and including the root certificate in PEM format).

In `SSLCACertificateFile` you have to use the cert (in PEM format as well) of the CA that signed the clients' certs.

Here's a complete example, keep in mind that I'm using a server cert signed by the same CA that signs the clients' certs for this. *Adjust if your needs differ.*

- Generating the certs 

  `openssl genrsa -des3 -out ca.key 4096
  openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -key ca.key -out ca.crt -subj "/C=US/ST=Some State/L=FancyTown/O=SomeOrg/CN=Self-Signed CA"
  openssl genrsa -out client.key 4096
  openssl req -new -key client.key -out client.csr -subj "/C=US/ST=Some State/L=FancyTown/O=SomeOrg/CN=client"
  openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in client.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -set_serial 01 -out client.crt
  openssl genrsa -out server.key 4096
  openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr -subj "/C=US/ST=Some State/L=FancyTown/O=SomeOrg/CN=server"
  openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -set_serial 02 -out server.crt`
- Moving them to a more convenient location 

  `mkdir /etc/ssl_ ; mv * /etc/ssl_`
- Install webserver and mod_ssl 

  `yum install -y httpd mod_ssl`
- Purge default TLS config 

  `truncate -s0 /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf`
- Common TLS config for all VHosts, `/etc/httpd/conf.d/00-ssl.conf`
  ```
  LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so

Listen                  443 https
SSLCACertificateFile    /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
SSLStaplingCache        shmcb:/run/httpd/stapling_cache(128000)
SSLUseStapling          off

SSLPassPhraseDialog     exec:/usr/libexec/httpd-ssl-pass-dialog
SSLSessionCache         shmcb:/run/httpd/sslcache(512000)
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300
SSLRandomSeed           startup file:/dev/urandom  256
SSLRandomSeed           connect builtin
SSLCryptoDevice         builtin

SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck  off
SSLProtocol             +TLSv1.2 -TLSv1.1 -TLSv1 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder     on

SSLCompression          off
SSLCipherSuite          ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:-ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AE
S256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:-RC4-SHA:AES256-
GCM-SHA384:AES256-SHA256:CAMELLIA256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES128-SHA:CAMELLIA128-SHA
```

- VHost config `/etc/httpd/conf.d/50-ssl-vhost.conf`

```

        ServerAlias localhost.localdomain localhost
        ServerName server
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/_ssl/server.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/_ssl/server.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/_ssl/ca.crt
        SSLCACertificateFile /etc/_ssl/ca.crt

```
    SSLVerifyClient require
    SSLVerifyDepth  10

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    <Directory /var/www/html>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
    TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
```

```

- Create an `index.html` file for testing
  `echo 'It works\!' > /var/www/html/index.html`
- Start httpd

`systemctl enable --now httpd`

- Add hostname

`echo '127.0.1.1 server' >> /etc/hosts`

- Test

This works (auth ok):
`( echo -en 'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: server\r\n\r\n' ; sleep 2) | openssl s_client -CAfile /etc/_ssl/ca.crt -cert /etc/_ssl/client.crt -key /etc/_ssl/cli
ent.key -connect server:443 -servername server`

This doesn't, we didn't provide a correct cert:

`( echo -en 'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: server\r\n\r\n' ; sleep 2) | openssl s_client -CAfile /etc/_ssl/ca.crt -connect server:443 -servername server`

Answer (score 0):

For our situation, we ended up making three changes:

1. Uncommented SSLCertificateChainFile and set it to RapidSSL's certificate chain file (who issued our certificate).
2. Changed SSLCACertificateFile to the CA chain file of the 3rd party's issuer (who issues their certificate).
3. Removed SSLCACertificateFile from the  directive.

Once we changed those and restarted, the two-way auth worked and they were able to access the API.

Thanks to @fuero for the help.